# DropDownList in fixed

Tags: c#, asp.net, servercontrols

I have some dropdownlists in a particular screen and whenever I get the value of the same, always comes the first value. What do I do to solve this, the dropdownlist in other pages work correctly and can select the value of them, this can not.

I'm setting the values ​​of this dynamically, every time I go up a file in the server folder, I upgraded, filling it with a vector that has the name (in string) of all items in the directory. When I select a different value than what comes standard on it, quyando'll get to play her value in the database, is as if I had not selected anything. I've tried to solve autoPorsback true and false, and nothing in the page_load. How do I fix this? I have no errors in the code.

NOTE: The drop down list is loaded EVERY TIME I climb a new file, as I do not have it in the IsPostBack. Every time I climb a new file, I have a method `MostraImagensCarrefadas()` that updates and populates the dropdownlist. This method gets the event of a button. I am not using update panel and nothing of the sort.

all my code for the component:

```
 //aspx header
<%@ Page Title="" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/administrativo/MasterPage.master"    EnableViewState="false" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="cadastroImovel.aspx.cs" Inherits="administrativo_cadastroImovel" %>

//dropdownlist in aspx
<div class="span2">
<div>
<asp:DropDownList ID="ddlImgPrincipal" runat="server" Width="160px" AutoPostBack="false" OnSelectedIndexChanged="ddlImgPrincipal_SelectedIndexChanged">
</asp:DropDownList>
 </div>
</div>

// Method page_load
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

    if (!IsPostBack)
    {

    }
}


//where I try to get the value of the dropdownlist
protected void btSalvar_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    eImoveis imovel = new eImoveis();

    imovel.area_total = txtArea.Text;
    imovel.bairro = txtBairro.Text;
    imovel.banheiro = txtBanheiro.Text;
    imovel.cep = txtCep.Text;
    imovel.cidade = ((System.Web.UI.WebControls.ListControl)     (ddlCidade)).SelectedValue.ToString();
    imovel.codcliente = ((System.Web.UI.WebControls.ListControl)    (ddlProprietario)).SelectedValue.ToString();
    imovel.codtipoimovel = ((System.Web.UI.WebControls.ListControl)    (ddlCategoriaImovel)).SelectedValue.ToString();
    imovel.complemento = txtComplemento.Text;
    imovel.descricao = txtDescricao.Text;
    imovel.garagem = txtVagasGaragem.Text;
    imovel.nome = txtNome.Text;
    imovel.numero = txtNúmero.Text;
    imovel.quarto = txtQuartos.Text;
    imovel.referencia = txtReferencia.Text;
    imovel.rua = txtRua.Text;
    //imovel.suite = sui
    imovel.valor = txtValor.Text;

    if (manImovel.Insere(imovel))
    {
        eImagens imagem = new eImagens();
        manImagem manImg = new manImagem();

        List<String> files = new manFile().getListFilesForDirectory(this, MAE.DIRETORIO_TEMP_IMG);

        DataTable dt = manImovel.getLastID(imovel);

        DataRow row = dt.NewRow();

        String codigo = dt.Rows[0].ItemArray[0].ToString();

        int tamanho = 0;            

        if (files != null)
        {
            foreach (String str in files)
            {
                imagem.cdImovel = codigo;
                imagem.imagem = str;


                if (ddlImgPrincipal.SelectedItem != null)
                {
                    if (ddlImgPrincipal.SelectedItem.ToString() == str)
                    {
                        imagem.imagemPrincipal = "SIM";

                    }
                }


                if (manImg.Insere(imagem))
                {
                    tamanho++;
                }

                //tamanho++;
            }
        }

        if (tamanho == files.Count)
        {
            if (new manFile().CopiaTodosOsArquivos(this, MAE.DIRETORIO_TEMP_IMG,     MAE.DIRETORIO_IMG))
            {
                if (new manFile().DeletaTodosArquivos(this, MAE.DIRETORIO_TEMP_IMG))
                {
                    MontaLiteralCarrossel();

                }
            }
        }
    }
}
 //Here I fill the dropdownlist
public void MostraImagensCarrefadas()
{
    List<String> files = new manFile().getListFilesForDirectory(this, MAE.DIRETORIO_TEMP_IMG);

    ddlImgPrincipal.Items.Clear();

    if (files != null)
    {
        foreach (String item in files)
        {
            ddlImgPrincipal.Items.Add(new ListItem(item));
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: From where do you call `MostraImagensCarrefadas` to add the items?

Comment: I put in the description

Comment: I know that it populates the DropDownList. That's why i've asked from where do you call it. And in what stage of the page's life-cycle are you calling `MostraImagensCarrefadas` exactly?

Comment: Sorry for not explaining well know, I'm starting with. Net now. The idea of this page is up images in a folder on server and every image I rise, dropdownlist be updated. When you click save, the data being thrown to the database, then all I've click the 'UPLOAD', if all goes well, the dropdownlist will be updated. The problem is that when I click save, even selecting any other value in the dropdownlist, the value in it is the same with ose I did not do anything = /.